# jQuery ajax post strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax function to calculate and perform a certain validation.

Code is shown below:

```
function collectFormData(fields) {
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var $item = $(fields[i]);
        data[$item.attr('name')] = $item.val();
    }
    return data;
}

function calculate(){
    var $form = $('#purchase-form');
    var $inputs = $form.find('[name]');
    var data = collectFormData($inputs);
    $.ajax({
        url: '${validateUrl}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="calculateBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calculate();">
  <spring:message code="button.calculate" />
</button>
```

However, as soon as the above function called my form is being submitted. What might cause this ?

Comment: Tahts coz you are calling the $ajax. in your calculate function. What is strange about that? :)

Comment: how do you trigger this `calculate()` function ?

Comment: yeah, exactly, which element that this function bind to? it's a button or something else?

Comment: What does collectFormData() look like?

Comment: @smk. Isn't ajax suppose to send request and receive response without submitting the whole page ?

Comment: There's no other listeners on that button?

Comment: give a return false in the calculate() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a form with a button, whose default behaviour is to submit the form. If you do not want to submit the form then you need to prevent the default action of the button on click.

Since you are using jQuery I recommend using jQuery to register the click event instead of using `onclick` attribute and the calculate method has to return `false` value to prevent the default click event from happening.

Change to

```
<button id="calculateBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
  <spring:message code="button.calculate" />
</button>

function calculate(){
    var $form = $('#purchase-form');
    var $inputs = $form.find('[name]');
    var data = collectFormData($inputs);
    $.ajax({
        url: '${validateUrl}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
$(function(){
    $('#calculateBtn').click(calculate)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but somehow the ajax validation is called twice.

Comment: did you remove `onclick="calculate();"`

Comment: It is a better approach since you are using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the 'type' attribute on the button to 'button'

```
<button type="button" id="calculateBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calculate();">
  <spring:message code="button.calculate" />
</button>
```

The default value of the type attribute is 'submit':  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button